# how to get facebook authorization code using wcf service

Tags: c#, facebook, wcf, authorization, facebook-access-token

I have wcf service function which uploads image to Facebook app.
how can i get the authorization code for this purpose.i need to generate the authorization code for the below purpose of user token generation.
how to generate the authorization code?

```
dynamic token = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
           {
               client_id = "104685639880509",
               client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
               redirect_uri = "http://localhost:50487/SRMPServiceApplication.svc",
               code = "code"
           });
```

Comment: I don't know about you but I don't think you should be showing the value for `client_secret` publicly.  You might want to **regenerate** a new one now for **security reasons**.

Comment: @Micky, is absolutely correct, you need to go reset your app secret __now__. Everyone can use the data you made available here as an app access token for your app, and change lots of app settings etc. via it. __Do. It. Now.__

Answer (score 0):

Generate extended authorization token from this link

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/

```
dynamic token = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
            {
                client_id = "104685639880509",
                client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                grant_type = "fb_exchange_token",
                fb_exchange_token = "your extended authorization token"
            });

            fb.AccessToken = token.access_token;
```

Comment: this is ok . i understand but where can i get the authorization code using wcf service?       dynamic token = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
           {
               client_id = "104685639880509",
               client_secret = "dc75c187d2826cb57ad000c321781b2d",
               redirect_uri = "http://localhost:50487/SRMPServiceApplication.svc",
               code = "code"
           });

Comment: how can i generate teh authorization code in first?

Comment: The documentation is available https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens